# Crontab not executing script with cURL

Tags: php, cron, curl

I have a cron that's set to run every ten minutes that works fine if I execute the file manually by entering

```
php register.php
```

But, my cron will not execute this file once it includes anything `cURL` related. My cron is as follows

```
*/10 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/register.php
```

I know that the cron is getting the correct file because at the very top of it, I put php's mail function to send me an email so that I know it was executed. But, anything cURL related will not execute. There aren't any global variables or server variables in the script, so that isn't the reason. I've checked both the crontab and the php error logs and nothing is there pertaining to this issue.

Comment: Please check the logfile, possibly /var/log/syslog: `grep CRON /var/log/syslog|less`  
If you see error messages, add them to your question.

Comment: Also post output that you received via mail. Is there some error related to cURL?

Answer (score 0):

check following all are correct.

(1)-f file.php   Parse and execute file

```
*/10 * * * * /usr/bin/php -f /var/www/html/register.php
```

(2)
give file following permission

```
 
chmod -x /var/www/register.php
```

(3)check which php

```
$ which php
/usr/bin/php
```

**if its diffrente then its affect your cron tab.**

(4)if you are using any url related operation in register(read,write -file etc...)
**then provide full path of your file.**

```
/var/www/path/to/file.php
```